# need to load inserts before updates before deletes into target...data is all in one source

Tags: oracle, informatica, informatica-powercenter, informatica-powerexchange

So, we're currently trying to achieve the following:

SourceTableA is a change data capture table, it will contain for a natural key, I, U, D, I then U, I then D, I then U then D, or U then D. Primary key for this table is the natural key + action (I, U, or D).

TargetTableA is a type-2 scd table with surrogate key generated by a sequence generator.

The main problem we're having is processing an update on a record which hasn't been inserted yet (surrogate key only exists in mapping and not in table), but came in the same pipeline.

We HAVE to process all records from SourceTableA in batch.

We can't use 3 different source qualifiers as I, U, D pipelines because of complex lookup logic.

We can't use dynamic cache to maintain a store of the generated surrogate keys because we can't control how Oracle will process the ins/upd/deletes. It was actually working, until we found out it was trying to update before inserting the referenced record.

I'm at wits end here.

Ex scenario of what should happen:

Insert record comes in, key is generated for this record, say 100. It is inserted with active_flag = 'Y' and end_date is 'open'.
Next, an update record comes in for the same natural key, a key is generated, 101, and the record with the new data is inserted with active_flag = 'Y'. Previously 'inserted' row 100 is deactivated to active_flag = 'N' and end_date = (update_row).end_date - 1 second.

Thanks!

Comment: Is the problem that your log table doesn't record the changes in the correct order, or is the problem that informatica is unable to apply the log in the correct order? In your source system you cannot update before insert so somewhere the record of the action in this order is being lost. Is this in the log table or in informatica?

Comment: The problem is because we have one pipeline, we can't control what gets inserted first. We tested this time and time again, and we ended up in a situation where it was trying to update something that hasn't been inserted yet. On the other hand, it was working fine by chance, it was updating an insert that came in the same batch of data only because the DB was inserting before the update.

Comment: If you are using a target lookup (static cache), it should not even work by chance. Because, the lookup cache is built before inserting any records. Dynamic cache lookup is one way to go. Another alternative might be to only insert all records (I, U) in the current mapping, and create a second mapping to update the active_flag and end date of the old records.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance but can't you push data through the pipeline in the exact order that the changes were logged? (PS I've never used informatica before)

Comment: @Samik this seems like the only option.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid not quite unfortunately, one pipeline means it passes all that data at once and it's up to the db to process it in whatever order (random)

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic lookup on target will fix this issue when source reads two records of same natural key since dynamic lookup will update the cache and then the target

Answer (score 0):

In Update Strategy set property to DD_Update for both Insert and also Update.
IN session level,mapping properties check only update else insert.

Hope it works!!